# How to choose the right loop statement in c# in my particular scenario?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, if-statement

I have two Tables T1 and T2 in which, where in T1 contains column name 'Year' which saves year information and T2 contains column name as 'P_year' which saves year information.

In the Table T1, I saved some data for the years '2011,2012,2013,2014'.
In the Table T2, I am saving the data for the years '2015,2016...and it goes on.

Now, I had developed a common webform to view the results, wherein I placed a dropdown for the year to choose all the years 2011,2012,2013,2014,2015...

And I am confused how to choose...like if the user has selected any particular year,...i.e.if the user has selected 2013,then I have to choose select statement related to table T1 and if the user has selected 2015, then I have to choose select statement related to table T2 ?

And if the user doesn't selects the year,How should I display all the data from both tables ?

```
if(year == "2011" !!year == "2012"!!year == "2013"!!year == "2014")
{
query1 = "select * from T1 where year ="Selected Year";
}
else if (year == "2015")
{
query2 = "select * from T2 where year ="2015";
}
else
{
query1 = "select * from T1 where year in('2011','2012','2013','2014');
query2 = "select * from T2 where year ="2015";
}
```

So,I can handle the execution in choosing the right query to execute if the user has selected any particular year. But issue rise up, if the user doesn't selects the year, I have to display the data from both tables executing both queries...like I have shown above in the last else statement.

So, Is there any way to write code in a optimized way.

Note:- Right here, I am just showing up a single lined query statement,but in real it exists for 5 or 6 lines of each select statements.

Anyone please help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although normally I would expect all the data to be in a single table, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT *
FROM T1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM T2
) T3
WHERE [Year]=@Year
```

Or if you want all the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT *
FROM T1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM T2
) T3
```

You might consider using an ORM like Entity Framework as well.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I think your query works if the year column name is same in both the tables. But in this scenario, it contains different column names which saves years information. I apologize for not mentioning it clearly initially.

Comment: @BhanuChandra it hardly matters you can use aliases.

Comment: Yes !!! It worked for me..Please Upvote the question too...as it might help to some other people who were in same situation like me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the table name in your drop down list with years. After selecting the year you choose the table name.

```
Datatable dt = new Datatable();
dt.Columns.Add("Year");
dt.Columns.Add("TableName");//May be hiden column
```

Comment: I am able to get the value of the year based on the user selection back in .cs. Issue is with how to chose the condition loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can prepare a single datatable with two columns as "Text", "Value"

In to the datatable assign values like below.

Text     Value
2011     T1
2012     T2

In the dropdownlist have the DataText field mapped to Text of datatable and have the DataValue field mapped to Value field of DataTable.

In dropdownlist_change event , you can capture both SelectedText and SelectedValue.
SelectedText will be 2011 and SelectedValue will be T1

Now you know which Table to use.
```

Comment: Hi, I am able to choose the right table. You can refer my question what I am tyring to do.